# How can I get Google.com in the language of my computer by default?

Tags: localization, google-search

Every time I go to pass through a Google page for something (e.g. to authenticate through my Gmail account), if I'm not logged in the page appears in the language of the country where I am (Dutch, in Belgium, which I don't speak), rather than the language of my browser or the language of my computer (English).

How could I change that and have Google page appear in English for me by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your browser sends `en` as the preferred language (visit http://echo.opera.com to check the *Accept-Language* header).

[image]

Note that it's not enough to list only English – Google discards that, likely under the assumption that it's a meaningless default value (e.g. fresh browser install).

Instead, the browser needs to list *both* English with high priority and some other language with low priority. If at least two languages are listed, then Google will actually honor the request and will use the highest-priority language.

```
Accept-Language: en-US, en, ru;q=0.9
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Google determines what you see as follows:

- Are you logged in? Yes: get the language from the logged in users preference
- No, Then what is the IP-address of the internet connection?
- Translate location based upon IP-address
- Redirect to google site in that language, such as google.be etc.

So, either login and stay logged in or use something like a VPN to route the traffic through your original country so Google will see that IP-address instead.